# Why (and how) does changing Windows10 region settings change valid character set of CString?

Tags: c++, windows, atl

I noticed that `CString` will give "string contains and invalid character" when a special character, in this case the degree symbol (°) is included with under some Windows 10 "Regional Format" settings and not others.

For example, with Windows 10 Settings Region --> Regional Format set to "English (United States)" all of the following `CString`s work properly with the degree symbol (°) in a Visual C++ app compiled with "Use multibyte character set" (using Visual Studio 2017).

However, if the Regional Format setting is changed to "English (Europe)", the first two methods result in "invalid character" and the degree symbol is replaced with the Unicode replacement character.

Why is the Regional Format option changing this behavior?
As far as I can tell, under both Regional Format settings the system encoding is cp1252, I expected this Windows 10 setting to only change the date / time format, but obviously something else is going on that I don't understand yet.

In addition, any advice on how should I be handling this in a legacy Windows application where the degree symbol is needed but the user may change the Regional format would be welcomed.

```
  #include <atlstr.h>

  // Works in English (United States), not in English (Europe)
  CString text;
  text.Format("Hello World! It's %d °F in RI today.", 32);
 
  // Works in English (United States), not in English (Europe)
  text = "Hello World! It's 32 °F in RI today.";

  // Works in English (Europe) + English (United States)
  text = L"Hello World! It's 32 °F in RI today.";

  // Works in English (Europe) + English (United States)
  CStringW text2;
  text2.Format(L"Hello World! It's %d °F in RI today.", 32);
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using ANSI/MBCS strings with non-ASCII characters to begin with.  They are very much dependent on not just the locale that the OS is set to, but also the locale that you use to compile your code. Mismatches cause data loss. You really should be using Unicode strings instead.

Comment: There are a lot of things that affect how non-ASCII characters are interpreted. There is the character set used by your editor, there's the translation character set, and there's the execution character set. I would start by dumping the bytes of the string to see how the degree symbol is encoded, and then see if that encoding matches your execution character set. What looks like a degree symbol in your editor might be hex B0 (code page Windows-1252), or it might be bytes C2 B0 (UTF-8 encoding).

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau! So would that basically look like compiling with "Use UNICODE character set" option set and modifying all string literals in the codebase with _T() macro (or even just L"" explicitly)?

Comment: Thanks @RaymondChen I'll give that a shot. So basically, that Regional Format setting having an effect on non-ascii char interpretation is not surprising to anyone? I definitely would expect it with a full on locale change, but in the Win10 settings that option looks like a date  / time format convention.